# How set animation-list as xml attribute

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

Is there a way to set and start an `xml` `animation-list` as an `xml` attribute? I can set and start it programmatically as follows:

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loadingImageView);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_animation);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
```

The animation-list is:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
//...
android:oneshot="false" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_anim_frame_one"
    android:duration="50"/>
 <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_anim_frame_two"
    android:duration="50"/>
```

etcetera.

Is there a way to do this with `xml` mark-up only, i.e no java code?

If not, is there a way to at least set it as an `xml` attribute and then start it programmatically?

I can't use rotation of a single drawable since the animation consists of several drawables in sequence.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603032/how-to-start-a-second-animation-list-after-the-end-of-first-animation-list?s=0|2.9229

Please help me solve my problem..I m stuck badly...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can declare it as

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="700"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:toYScale="1.4" />

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="700"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />

</set>
```

Just a reference. You would have to change animation type and parameters. And as per my knowledge, you will have to start it using java.

Edit:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136258/how-to-load-animationdrawable-from-xml-file) is the link that can be helpful for animation list

Comment: Thanks. I have to use an animation-list since the animation consists of several drawables in sequence, not an animation of a single drawable. I'm not sure how I can use your suggestion given this. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136258/how-to-load-animationdrawable-from-xml-file . Chck it. It might help

Comment: The link is very helpful. If you edit it into to your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should first load the animation:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation_name);

img.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  My code for loading it and starting it in java works fine. I'm looking for a way to refactor it so at least I can set the animation-list to the image view in an xml layout. So, it's the xml part I'm curious about.

Answer (score 0):

Adding example with alpha & translation for future reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```