# how to start a second animation-list after the end of first animation-list

Tags: android, animation

i want to start a second animation-list after the end of first animation-list
first animation-list is(list_first):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/f11"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/f12"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

</animation-list>
```

Second animation-list is(list_second):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/s21"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/s22"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

</animation-list>
```

now how to start the second animation list at the end of first list?

```
ImageView img1;
TextView t1;

AnimationDrawable splashanimation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.anim_layout);

    img1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.anim_imgview);
    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_first);
    splashanimation = (AnimationDrawable)img1.getBackground();
    splashanimation.start();
```

Now over here i am not getting what to do to ? how to start the second animation list on the end of first list..please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
splashanimation = (AnimationDrawable)img1.getBackground();
splashanimation.start();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                            //start your 2nd animation
                            //secondAnimation.start();
                       }
                    }, delay);//delay = the duration of your first animation, i think its 3000 in your case
```

Or you can combine the 2 xml animation in one:

`combine_anim.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/f11"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/f12"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/s21"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/s22"
android:duration="500"/>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/delay"
android:duration="1000"/>

</animation-list>
```

And you use `combine_anim.xml` as background instead of `list_first.xml`

Comment: dear @user4782849 thank you for your time and consideration...the problem i am facing is: (first problem) when i place splashanimation.start() inside a handler it is crashing giving error as VM does not provide monitor information. i have no clue why it is happening ?

Comment: (second) i have a very long sequence of animation list that i need to play one after the another i.e. for example  list 2 , list 4, list 3, list 2 ,list 6 , list 2, list 5 , list 5  like this in a randomized manner..i am  selecting a particular list and then have to play  the animation in the following sequence. the question i posted contains only the part of this problem. please suggest