# Display Animation using animation drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have read in the android developer website this how you can turn sequence of images into animation. But nothing is displayed.neither the image and not the animation.

```
package org.example.anim;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
     img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

      // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable  
       frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

      // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
     }

 public void onWindowFocusChanged()
 {

    frameAnimation.start();
 }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have exactly written my animation xml file exactly like the one you posted. if there is any other problem maybe with the activitymain.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have added multiple images and also if your spin_animation is list like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

then code must work,i think you haven't generated this list properly.also see this link for more help [animation drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136258/how-to-load-animationdrawable-from-xml-file)

Comment: I do exactly like that but it displayed the first image only.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ImageView progressSpinner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progressSpinner);

    // Set the background of the image - In this case an animation
    // (/res/anim folder)
    progressSpinner.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.progress_animation);
    // Get the image background and attach the AnimationDrawable to it.
    progressAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) progressSpinner.getBackground();
    progressAnimation.start();
```

Move the image from drawable to anim folder and try this code in your onCreate.

Comment: do i move the images or the .xml animation file?

Comment: move the full xml file to your anim folder inside res it should be something like this res-->anim---> ur xml

Comment: hope the answer was helpful