# Animate seekbar thumb in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-seekbar

I have designed a call screen, where i have used a seekbar to receive/disconnect incoming call.If i'll move seekbar to the left side of the screen, call will be disconnected and if to the right side of the screen, call will be received.I have already implemented that logic.

Problem is that,whenever someone calls,I want to show some animation in the seekbar thumb as displayed in the image below.

[image: animated thumb]

Comment: Maybe a AnimationDrawable as thumb could work. Just an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2136328/2139738